3rd OS installed: Grub does not remember last selection?
I had a dual boot Ubuntu 22 and Windows 10.
I added 3rd OS Ubuntu 20.
However, now the Grub does not remember my last choice and I always have to be carefull on startup if I want to load the last OS I was using.
What happened with 3rd OS installation to mess this up? I checked my /etc/default/grub on Ubuntu 22, and it looks OK:
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

Not sure which Grub should I look into, the one on U22 or the U20 which I just installed?

Your grub configuration from 22.04 looks ok, but now you use the grub from the new OS. So you have to configure this one.

Your last installed OS usually controls the boot process; so that's the grub you need to change.  You can make other OSes take control easily using grub-install (which I do myself as I regularly QA test installs re-installing one system one a multi-boot machine). Be aware that some differences in grub 2.06 & later can influence this (esp. if non-Ubuntu which use different defaults).

@guiverc Thanks. Could you give more details related to grub-install and add all this as answer?
